# Is it possible to change, clone directory, when creating repo using GitHub CLI?

Tags: pycharm, github-cli

I use PyCharm to work on my Python projects, and I use the standard procedure of creating the project

**Open Pycharm -> New Project -> Specify the Location -> Specify "New Virtualenv environment" -> Create**

Now from this directory, I use GitHub CLI to create my repo on github like so

```
gh repo create MyProject
```

These are the prompted options

```
? Visibility Public                               
? Would you like to add a .gitignore? Yes   
? Choose a .gitignore template Python                                  
? Would you like to add a license? No    
? This will create the "MyCoolProject" repository on GitHub. Continue? Yes   
✓ Created repository Razvi/MyProject on GitHub
? Clone the remote project directory "Razvi/MyProject"? (Y/n)
```

The last question when answered "Yes" clones the remote project directory by creating new directory in the existing directory like so

[image: Default]

What I would like is to bypass the redundant "MyProject" directory (marked red) inside the initial "MyProject" directory (marked green).

[image: Expected]

How do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by initializing the directory before creating the repo

Create a Python Project in PyCharm as usual.

1. Initialize your project directory as main git branch using

   ```
   git init -b main
   ```
2. Create your repo using GitHub CLI

   ```
   gh repo create MyProject
   ```

   You will have the following options

   ```
   ? Visibility Public                               
   ? Would you like to add a .gitignore? Yes   
   ? Choose a .gitignore template Python                                  
   ? Would you like to add a license? No    
   ? This will add an "origin" git remote to your local repository. Continue? Yes
   ```

   This will create the repo with **.gitignore** file at the main directory level.
3. Now pull the main branch using

   ```
   git pull origin main
   ```

You have your project set-up as required.